# Multi-booting in my laptop

Tags: partitioning

I have 3 primary partitions-one is system reserved (created by windows 7 automatically when installed),another one is windows 7 and the remaining one is EXTRAS(D:).I have 72 GB free space.I want to use 4 operating systems including Windows 7.The remaining 3 are-Kali,Ubuntu and Debian.Now,I have 4 GB RAM.I will always save my personal files to the 'EXTRAS' partition(320 GB),so according to the official documentation,I have to spare 8 GB for swap.So,I will have total amount of (72-8) GB=64 GB space to install the 3 OSes.I am planning to leave 24 GB for Ubuntu,20 GB for Kali and 20 GB for Debian.Will it be okay?Or,do I have to make separate /home partition for each one of them?I heard that home partition is for saving personal datas and system configuration(which will be less than 1 GB in most cases).I also heard that in 10 GB,12 GB and 8 GB; Ubuntu,Kali and Debian should be running fast(respectively).So.if I don't create a separate home partition,and instead of that provide extra 1GB(app setting)++9 GB(for small amount of data)=10 GB total,will my system run finely?(in case of Ubuntu-1GB ++13GB and in case of Kali 1GB++7GB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

20 GB or more should be plenty for those Linux distros. The minimum space requirements you found are plenty for installing quite a few programs.

The 8 GB of swap is suggested but not required, since you have the space you might as well use 8 GB.

Leaving 10 GB for user settings and files sounds fine since you will store most of your files on the larger "EXTRAS" partition.